# How to set the span value with other value and copy past in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Need to copy only `Ref - SO/RL-2104970` and paste it in Excel.
but got error:**object variable or block variable not set** for both 2 last line method

```
Sub so()
   Dim ie As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim sr As Variant
    Dim sNum As String
    Dim idd As String
    Dim rw, tbl As Object, r As Long
  
    Windows("Indus.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("4th2300").Select
c = Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Range("h" & c + 1) <> "" And Range("I" & c + 1) = "" Then
       
   c = c + 1
   Range("h" & c).Select
   Selection.Copy
    
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
         
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows

        If .Count > 0 Then
          ' Get IE
          Set ie = .Item(.Count - 1)
        Else
          ' Create IE
          Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
          ie.Visible = True
        
           End If

      End With
          
          
       ie.Visible = True
       While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
   
    ie.navigate "https://ismartcube.industowers.com/iSmartCube/Screens/Home.aspx?siteId=1&menuItemId=193"
    
    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    
    Set doc = ie.document
   
   
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
   
        
           
               
                 idd = "ctl00_TabsControl1_lblAppTitle"
                 a=doc.getElementById(idd).innerText
             a=doc.getElementById("ctl00_TabsControl1_lblAppTitle").innerText
  
End Sub
```

HTML code

```
 <div id="divMainColumn">
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$hidMove" id="ctl00_hidMove">
                <div class="contentHolderiFrame">
                    
                    <div style="clear:both;"><img src="../Images/clear.gif" alt="" width="1px" height="10px"> </div>
                    
                    <div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowA1Form1(id) {
        if (parseInt(id) > 0) {
            window.location = "../ShareRequest/LaunchShareRequestFlow.aspx?requestId=" + id;
        }
    }
    function ShowRelocationForm1(id,type) {
        if (parseInt(id) > 0) {
            if (type == "NewNominal")
            {
                window.location = "../PreRollout/LaunchPrerolloutRequestFlow.aspx?requestId=" + id;
            }
            else
            {
                window.location = "../ShareRequest/LaunchShareRequestFlow.aspx?requestId=" + id;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div>
<a id="ShowAnchor" name="ShowAnchor"></a>
<span id="ctl00_TabsControl1_UpdatePanel1"> 
    
    
   <div id="ctl00_TabsControl1_divTabsHeader">
   <div class="siteTabsHeader" id="siteTabs">
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
              <ul id="ctl00_TabsControl1_ApplicationTabsList"> 
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_TabsControl1_divstyle1" style="clear:both;margin-top:22px;"></div>
      <div class="rollOutTabsBg">
            <div class="siteRef floatLeft"><span id="ctl00_TabsControl1_lblAppTitle">Ref - SO/RL-2104970</span></div>
            <div style="padding-top:2px;" class="RollOutTabs">
                <ul>
                    <span id="ctl00_TabsControl1_ApplicationTabs" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;"><span>
                                <li class="tab_act1"><a href="../UpgradePreRollout/UpgradeServiceOrderEdit.aspx?parentId=18" class="tab_act1" title="Click to go to optional products service order">Optional Products Service Order</a></li>
                        </span></span>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
        
    </tbody></table>
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$OtherDetailsPlanning2$hidRequestId" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_OtherDetailsPlanning2_hidRequestId" value="4224296">
</div>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" valign="top">
                                    <div class="divHeader">
                                        Service Order Details
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divContent">
                                        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" summary="0">
                                            <tbody><tr valign="top">
                                                <td style="width: 50%">
                                                    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="0">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblCustomerSONo">Customer SO No.</span><span class="attention">*</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblCustomerSONoCol">:</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCustomerSONo" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCustomerSONo" title="Please enter customer SO No" class="textBox">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDate">Date</span><span class="attention">*</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateCol">:</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div class="floatLeft" style="padding-right: 3px;">
                                                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtDate" type="text" value="20/07/2020" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dtDate" title="Please enter date" class="textBox" size="6">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_calDate" title="Click to select date" src="../Images/cal_ico.gif" alt="Click to select date" style="border-width:0px;">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTargetDate">Target Date</span><span class="attention">*</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="formLabel">
                                                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTargetDateCol">:</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div class="floatLeft" style="padding-right: 3px;">
                                                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtTargetDate" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dtTargetDate" title="Please enter target date" class="textBox" size="6">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_calTargetDate" title="Click to select target date" src="../Images/cal_ico.gif" alt="Click to select target date" style="border-width:0px;">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rowoldMessage">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you clarify your question by improving the formatting? When editing the question, click the "?" for tips on **How to Format**.

Comment: sir now pls help...mention my query by question 1,2,3

Comment: I added some additional formatting to make things more clear, but it's still a bit confusing. I'd suggest reducing things down to **one** question only. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your question(s). Good luck.

Comment: Explaining what exactly is going wrong would be helpful. Error messages, etc.

Comment: hi pls help now